# How to use 3 trained Keras models(.h5) to make voting predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training a model for posture recognition using three channel image sources

So now I have 3 CNN models (*.h5) and inputs are (224,224,3)

And I want to do the soft voting and hard voting in my models

Can "EnsembleVoteClassifier" or "votingclassifier" complete that?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to specify the model the outputs

Comment: I have 3 prediction set of untrained images of the same category, and I want to combine them with accuracy.
What do you mean about the output?